# Load tab content after tab is selected, and delete loaded content from previously selected tab

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui and I created a simple Login and Register page. 
[image: This is the login page]

What I am trying to do is to load the content of each tab after they have been selected, and delete the loaded content from the previous tab.
I am using material-ui and react

Comment: You can acheive this by using conditional rendering. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html . Split your App to <Login /> and <Register /> components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!